# Sponsoring Schengen visa for parents-in-law (no income proof)

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas

I would like to take my wife and her parents to Europe **with us** this winter (for a couple of weeks) from India. I'm wondering how difficult it would be to get a visa for them. I would be the complete sponsor for my wife and my in-laws.

I've been to Europe 5 times so far and visited 20 countries in the Schengen zone (all in good standing) and so has my wife. I can show more than the sufficient proof of funds (for everyone I am sponsoring), proof of fixed assets (property) in India and stable income for me and my wife.

I am **30 years old, my wife is 28 and my in-laws are 61 and 49**. My in-laws are have income in cash from home business (no business registration) in their personal account (though not enough to fund their own trip). They have never visited any country outside India before and we would like to take them to Europe as a first visit to a first world country.

I would like to know if it would be a challenge to apply for a Schengen visa (without having any business proof) but having me as their sponsor. We are planning for France, Sweden and Finland. I'm an **Indian citizen** staying in India and so are they.

Additional info : They will have 3 years income tax return by the time they apply for the visa. Though proof of their business is not present since its a home business and their income is in cash. Also there are no proof of their fixed assets.

Comment: Can they provide evidence that they have good reason to return home at the end of the trip? Proof of income is partly about showing this, but they might have other ties to their home country they could show.

Comment: I don't see any reason they can provide to show ties to the home country. we would obviously return with them. We would both take complete responsibility for them. In fact, even if offered, they wouldn't stay back in Europe (since they do not know anyone there, or the language or have enough funds to sustain) Are there chances that this would be red flagged / rejected ? What can we do to bolster their chances of getting a schengen visa ?

Comment: Could they start building up an income and tax history and delay applying until it is established?

Comment: yes, they could do that. we are planning a trip for 2019, so they could have income tax returns of 2 years by the time they apply. But are income tax returns enough to prove connections to home country ?

Comment: There is no set formula for this and nobody on the internet can guarantee a successful application but verifiable evidence like bank statements and tax receipts are helpful.

Comment: You could show documents about business you have in india. 
1. Bank statements, 2. Property 3. Pension details .

Comment: Do you have any relatives in the European Union? This really simplifies the procedure

Answer (score 2):

We are dealing with the same situation. I have asked and confirmed that a son-in-law (my husband) can sponsor the hotel and flight reservations for his in-laws (my parents). You need to attach your passport copy and mention this in your in- law's covering letter as well as in a separate letter from the sponsor (you). 
It will help having a strong sponsoring letter mentioning why and how much you will sponsor, your bank statements, salary certificate, relationship etc. Also attach financial assets of your in-laws to reduce the look of complete dependency.
Though there is no guarantee, hopefully this will help.